# Convert date format in php and javascript to unix time

Tags: javascript, php, date

What is the best way to convert date from japan format to regular format in php and javascript

I have the date: 2016年04月01日

So I want to convert that to the unix timestamp.

I try to do that in JS, but I think its seem to be not right .

```
        var val=$('#from_date').val();
        var st = val.replace(/\D/g,'-');
        var dateParts = st.split('-');
        var date = new Date(dateParts[0], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[2]);
        $('#date_from').val(Date.parse(date));
```

And what I got is : 1459443600000 (unix time in milliseconds) = 1459443600 in UNIX TimeStamp.
But when I use http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm to check . It show me the date is : Thu, 31 Mar 2016 17:00:00 GMT. Why it is the yesterday . Why its not 00:00:00 GMT ?

Same on PHP when I use `strtotime` function.

Can somebody explain for me about this issue ?

Can you tell me the better method to convert time in japan format to unix time. For example: 2016年04月01日. And I want : 1459468800(Fri, 01 Apr 2016 00:00:00 GMT)

Thank you .

Comment: Why replace, then split? Consider `dateParts = st.split(/\D/)`, and why `Date.parse(date)`? Just `+date` or `date.getTime()` will do.

Comment: You are converting a local date to UTC, so the difference is your timezone (which is likely UTC+0700). 2016-03-31T17:00:00.000Z is 2016-04-01T00:00:00.000+0700 (i.e. they are exactly the same instant in time but in different timezones).

Comment: Oh, in the above, "your" timezone means the timezone of the host on which the code is executed. The Date object itself has no concept of timezone.

Comment: thank you. That the timezone.